# Does Apple scale down iPhone 4 resolution screenshots for iPhone 3 on your app page?

Tags: ios, iphone

When I'm submitting my iOS app, there's a place where I can upload screenshots under the heading "iPhone and iPod Touch screenshots". If I upload an iPhone4 **960x480** screenshot, will it be excluded from iPhone3's app store listing because iPhone3's **480x320** screen can't fit such a size? Or does Apple downscale for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screenshots are scaled down to fit the screen, but quality is not lost. It's basically like using `image@2x.png`.

Comment: Should I just exclusively submit in 960x480 then, since that will work across all phones? Any advantage to submit in 480x320?

Comment: no advantage to submitting in a lower resolution. You basically want the best image quality to show off your app do you not? YOu can only benefit form submitting in a higher resolution.